# Example AngularJS not working

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to learn Angularjs from a book. However, I typed in the following code from the book and it doesn't work in Chrome:

```
    <html ng-app='myApp'>
<head>
<title>Your Shopping Cart</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller='CartController'>
<h1>Your Order</h1>
<div ng-repeat='item in items'>
<span>{{item.title}}</span>
<input ng-model='item.quantity'>
<span>{{item.price | currency}}</span>
<span>{{item.price * item.quantity | currency}}</span>
<button ng-click="remove($index)">Remove</button>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
function CartController($scope) {
$scope.items = [
{title: 'Paint pots', quantity: 8, price: 3.95},
{title: 'Polka dots', quantity: 17, price: 12.95},
{title: 'Pebbles', quantity: 5, price: 6.95}
];
$scope.remove = function(index) {
$scope.items.splice(index, 1);
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It just shows the braces. I don't need this solved, i just want to know if this is an old book or something.
Does this work for anyone else?

Comment: Where is declared your module "myApp" ?

Comment: dfsq, I'm sorry i don't understand. isn't the angular script in the bottom of the page?

Comment: you have to declare an `angular app` and then add the controller `CartController` to the app

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to declare your controller in the module called 'myApp'as your html markup shows it `<html ng-app='myApp'>`:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('CartController', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
{title: 'Paint pots', quantity: 8, price: 3.95},
{title: 'Polka dots', quantity: 17, price: 12.95},
{title: 'Pebbles', quantity: 5, price: 6.95}
];
$scope.remove = function(index) {
$scope.items.splice(index, 1);
}
});
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/RHsvoTY3KRa2jhmJBtqL?p=preview)

Comment: so is this an old version of the book? that code was pasted directly from it

Comment: This book was written before Angular 1.2 obviously.